bash: java: command not found
My Linux distro is Debian 12.7.0, 64bit, English.
I modified the guide titled How to install Java JDK 21 or OpenJDK 21 on Debian 12
so that I could "install"/use the latest production-ready release of OpenJDK 23.0.1 (FYI Debian's official repos contain OpenJDK 17 which is outdated for my use.)
I clicked the link https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk23.0.1/c28985cbf10d4e648e4004050f8781aa/11/GPL/openjdk-23.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz to download the software to my computer.
Next I extracted the zipped file using the below command:
tar xvf openjdk-23.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz

A new directory was created on my device. It is called jdk-23.0.1
I copied said directory to /usr/local
sudo cp -r jdk-23.0.1 /usr/local

I created a new source script to set the Java environment by issuing the following command:
su -i
tee -a /etc/profile.d/jdk23.0.1.sh<<EOF
> export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk-23.0.1
> export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
> EOF

After having done the above, I opened jdk23.0.1.sh using FeatherPad and the contents showed the following:
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk-23.0.1
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/bin

Based on the guide, I typed the following command:
source /etc/profile.d/jdk23.0.1.sh

To check the OpenJDK version on my computer, I typed:
java --version

An error message appeared:
bash: java: command not found

Could someone show me what I did wrong please? Thanks.
P.S. I followed said guide very closely and yet there was the error message.
Edited to correct the typo. The correct statement should be as follows:
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk-23.0.1

You need to quote the first EOF when you tee so that $JAVA_HOME (and $PATH) won't be expanded at that point.

You do not define the proper path in this command: export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk-21

@TomYan I don't quite understand what you meant. Could you elaborate please?

@RomeoNinov (1) What should be the proper path please? That was what the writer of the guide https://green.cloud/docs/how-to-install-java-jdk-21-or-openjdk-21-on-debian-12/ wrote. (2) There was a typo in my original post. It should be export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk-23.0.1

@Renesah, JAVA_HOME need to be JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk-23.0.1 and after that the PATH to be PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

@Renesah, and in Debian there is JDK package: https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=openjdk , use proper way!

@RomeoNinov I know there is an OpenJDK package in Debian but as I have written in my original post, Debian's version of OpenJDK is too old. It's version 17 whereas I need at least version 21 because the other software needs it.

If you run:
tee -a /etc/profile.d/jdk23.0.1.sh<<EOF
> export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk-23.0.1
> export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
> EOF

The shell script would, as you mentioned, contain:
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk-23.0.1
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/bin

which is obvious wrong because you really want the second line to be:
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

so that the variables would be expanded as the script is being sourced, and, after that, the value of the environment variable PATH (not the content of the script) would become (note the last bits):
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/jdk-23.0.1/bin

if the value (of that of the respective shell) was:
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

before sourcing the script.
The reason you have "unexpected" content in the produced script is that, without quoting the first EOF when you run the tee command, the shell where you run it will expand the variables in the heredoc.
And because $JAVA_HOME wasn't set in the shell where/when you run the command (the heredoc is an input for tee; it will not be sourced "on the fly" while you were feeding it to tee; nor will it be sourced automatically after that), when the variable was expanded by the shell (before feeding the heredoc to tee), it is expanded to an "empty string" instead of /usr/local/jdk-23.0.1. That's why you get (a second) :/bin at the end of the second line.
To suppress the expansion, you should run:
tee -a /etc/profile.d/jdk23.0.1.sh<<"EOF"
> export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk-23.0.1
> export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
> EOF

instead.

Also note that scripts in /etc/profile.d/ will normally be sourced by any (new) "login" shell (here it really just means e.g. bash started with -l), and usually even when the shells attached to an terminal emulator might be "non-login" ones, they will still inherit the environment one way or another from some process / shell that source the scripts there. So after a re-login, you shouldn't need to manually source the newly created script (again).

Also note that PATH "component" near the end will have lower precedence, which means with :$JAVA_HOME/bin appended to PATH, if you install some other / older jdk package with the system package manager, it will be used instead of this jdk you have in /usr/local/. So depending on what you want, you may want to prepend instead.
Moreover, if the system jdk package ships a similar script, you will even need to make sure your script has a filename that makes itself lexically-ordered later (which could vary depending on the current locale, I think), so that it will be sourced later.

I really appreciate your taking the time and effort to write such a detailed explanation. (1) To be honest, I don't know anything about shell scripting and such. I am just an end-user who depends on said guide to "install" OpenJDK 23.0.1. My other software needs at least version 21. (2) It's obvious that said guide contains errors and I blindly followed them verbatim.

You wrote: So depending on what you want, you may want to prepend instead. How do I prepend in the PATH component? Can you show it to me by way of an example please? Thanks.

Well, obviously PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH? It's just string concatenation.

Thanks. I just put what I wish to prepend at the beginning of the string.
